# How do I maintain session in Rails app with support for multiple domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-5, multiple-domains

Here's the scenario:

I have a Rails app running on a single machine. The app for the sake of this discussion is a content management system and will be used to serve multiple sites in a network. It can be reached at `app.com`. Users should be able to setup a custom domain for their site.

What I'm struggling with is how to maintain the session so that a user only has to sign into the network once. If they visit any site on the network, their session should be maintained. (Technically, the user is still on the same site just with a custom URL for the site their visiting.)

**How do I maintain the session for the user across all sites on the app?**

Based on what I've read about cookies, this is difficult b/c cookies cannot be shared between unique domains. What I'm looking for is help understanding the parts of the problem at play. I'm game to write Rack Middleware or add other tech in front of the app if that's what it takes. Eventually, I'd like to make it possible for each of these domains to use HTTPS, but let's start leave that out for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer sessions through a series of redirects.

Let's say you have an app with the domain of `platform.com` and you host custom domains such as `customdomain.com` on this platform. As described in the question, whenever a user is logged in on `platform.com` they should be logged in on all hosted domains.

The basic idea works like this:

1. User signs in to `platform.com`
2. User requests a page on `customdomain.com`
3. App server sees the request from the `customdomain.com` and sees that the user is not logged in to `customdomain.com`.
4. App server redirects to `platform.com/get_session?redirect=customdomain.com`
5. App server redirects to `customdomain.com/set_session?login_token=<HASH>`
6. App server sets session cookie in response to `set_session`

Voila!! The user's session is now transferred from `platform.com` to `customdomain.com`.

*Caveat: The challenge here is in the details of when the app decides to redirect. You need to add logic to ensure you don't end up in an infinite redirect cycle.*